# Google AppsScript and Drive API v2 - Change google platform project programmatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

**What I want to do**

1. Copy a google sheet programmatically via API.
2. Change the copied sheet's cloud platform project to the original sheets project, when copied Google creates a new google platform project, that's not what I want.
3. Get the script id of the copied sheet.

All of the above only programmatically, I already know how to do these things manually by clicking menu's.

**What I have already tried:**

1. This [google documentation article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects) tells me how to change a platform project manually, I want to do the same thing via some API that Google may be providing.
2. You can copy a sheet programmatically [via this API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy), however you can't get the associated script id or the project and it doesn't let me set the cloud platform project.
3. I know how to get the script id from within the sheet, I want to do this from outside the sheet.

*Note that the API's I need have to be accessible via outside the sheet, via a program that I host myself.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized what I was really looking for were Add on's. Via that I can keep the apps script project as one which solves all my requirements.

Read more about App Script addons from this google doc page: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/